# How to use "using" statement in a controller that returns a File?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an API controller that returns a file from a stream as follows:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetImage (string id)
{
    var stream = await _fileService.GetImage(id);
    return File(stream, "image/jpeg");
}
```

When I use `using` statement around the stream as given below, and return the File, I get an error "Cannot access a disposed object".

```
using(var stream = await _fileService.GetImage(id))
{
    return File(stream, "image/jpeg");
}
```

So, my questions are:

1. Should I use the `using` statement at all while retrieving the file?
2. Is there anything else that we should use to discard the stream?
3. Does the stream get automatically discarded since it's a read operation and hence may we not need the `using` statement?

Comment: When posting on Stack Overflow and you have the urge to type *"I get an error"*, always remember to copy that error and paste it into your question.